# Naming Structure for Create Node Page template?

Tags: theming, nodes

I need to create a custom template for:
/node/add/node

It's currently using:
page--node.tpl.php

What's the file naming convention for this?

Answer (score 0):

"page--node--add--nodetype.tpl.php" overides it.